# Latest Phonegap source shows several critical and high security risks via Fortify scan

Tags: security, cordova, fortify

I have a Phonegap app that is merely a browser shell for a responsive web app and the results from a Fortify security scan reveals a large number of critical and high risks.

I am not finding much help on Google and so is there anything that can be done aside from attempting to rewrite some of the Phonegap source?

It seems odd that such a reputable framework would have set off so many red flags. The code I added is limited to a few lines and there is not much I can do so the large majority seem to stem from the framework's source.

Issues by Fortify Priority Order
Low 145
High 127
Critical 2

Comment: Fortify has a lot of false positives. Have you reviewed the results to make sure the results are all valid?

Comment: This is what I thought but the scan is being conducted by a government agancy which the client is under and I only have access to the generic report results. I am working on obtaining a copy of the scanning tool so that I can see if I can alter the results or see a more detailed report. This is frustrating to say the least.

Comment: From experience, I can tell you that you'll find maybe 10% of the results valid, and at that point, you should really get in touch with the phonegap team (maybe via IRC, or other means) to figure out whether they can fix it. I would suspect they've gone through a scan looking at how they're an Adobe company now.